# How to determine type of array in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Here is the code:

```
const func = (...args: [string, {a: true}] | [number, {b: true}]) => {
  if (typeof args[0] === 'string') {
    return args[1].a;
  } else {
    return args[1].b;
  }
}
```

And typechecking failes to determine the shape of `args` variable. Is it somehow possible to do?

I expect that the example code doesn't show any TS errors

Comment: The type of `args` is not a [discriminated union](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) because `string` and `number` are not valid types for a *discriminant* (which must be a unit/singleton/literal type).  There's no built-in method to narrow non-discriminated unions by checking properties. You could write your own type guard functions and use them, like [this](//tsplay.dev/ND216W) perhaps. Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  Please mention @jcalz if you reply to notify me.

Comment: @jcalz It never crossed my mind that we can’t use primitive types as a discriminant. Learned something new today. Is this something documented by TypeScript? I tried looking at their docs and can’t find this being mentioned.

Comment: @Terry If I write up an answer here I will make sure to include links to sources ([ms/TS#48500](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48500) is a reasonable place to start); right now I'm waiting to hear back from the OP on whether I'm missing anything about the question before I expend too much effort on it.

Comment: @jcalz yes, you exactly answered my question! I thought primitive types could not be used as a discriminated type. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a ch... oh you just accepted caTS's answer.  That's fine but I probably won't bother putting more effort in here.  Good day to you!

Comment: @jcalz hm, but can I accept two answers? You solution is more general. Or if you will write the answer I will change the accepted answer to yours 

Comment: I don't like to poach points from people if I can help it.  Maybe @caTS will edit their answer with whatever you want to see from mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to "artificially" narrow the type of `arg`:

```
function firstIsString(arg: [unknown, unknown]): arg is [string, unknown] {
    return typeof arg[0] === "string";
}

const func = (...args: [string, { a: true }] | [number, { b: true }]) => {
    if (firstIsString(args)) {
        return args[1].a;
    } else {
        return args[1].b;
    }
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wEBKON)

Comment: Unfortunately there is a type error at the line `firstIsString(args)`, no?

Comment: @Terry Whoops, it didn't error when I first typed that in. It looks like a generic is not necessary either.

Comment: Wow, interesting workaround. Thanks!